# CheckBox causes validation only on Check, not on Uncheck

Tags: asp.net, checkbox, webforms, postback, validation

I observed a very strange behavior on my ASP.NET WebForms page. I have some input controls with one or more validators assigned to them.

Simplified example of a `TextBox` input control:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBoxX" runat="server" 
CausesValidation="True"></asp:TextBox>

<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="V1" runat="server" 
ControlToValidate="TextBoxX"
ErrorMessage="blah blah"
EnableViewState="False" />

<asp:RangeValidator ID="V2" Type="Integer" runat="server"
ControlToValidate="TextBoxX" 
ErrorMessage="blah blah"
MinimumValue="0" MaximumValue="9999" 
EnableViewState="False" />

<asp:CustomValidator ID="V3" runat="server"
ErrorMessage="blah blah"
OnServerValidate="MyCustomValidateMethod" 
EnableViewState="False" 
EnableClientScript="False" />
```

EnableViewState is intentionally set to false to keep the network load low. V3 is the one of interest. On the server, my custom method, will validate upon plausibility of the value.

```
protected void MyCustomValidateMethod(object source, ServerValidateEventArgs args)
{//...}
```

Up to here everything works as expected. But I also have a checkbox that allows the user to explicitly override the plausibility check, after a warning is displayed.

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBoxOverride" runat="server" Text="You can override here!"
AutoPostBack="True" 
CausesValidation="True"  />
```

Checking/unchecking the `CheckBox` causes the postback as expected, **but the validators (and especially the "V3" one) are only called when the box gets checked, but not when it gets unchecked!**

What does cause this strange behaviour and how to fix it?

Here is some more information:

- I am using .NET 3.5.
- The whole stuff here is inside a single UpdatePanel, if that matters.
- I can explicitly call `Page.Validate();` on postback, but this seems dirty to me, and the validators get then called twice when the checkbox gets checked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since there seems to be no solution, I helped myself with a workaround: The CheckBox will no more cause validation, but trigger a postback on a change:

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBoxOverride" runat="server" Text="You can override here!"
AutoPostBack="True"    
oncheckedchanged="Override_CheckedChanged" />
```

Then, in the change handler, the validation is invoked:

```
protected void Override_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)    {
        Page.Validate();
}
```

This now works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set `ValidateEmptyText` to `true`.

Are you missing a `ControlToValidate` on the `CustomValidator`?

Comment: I have set ValidateEmtpyText to true on the V3 validator, but it does not change the behavior.

Comment: I intentionally miss the ControlToValidate, because the the validation does not only rely on the control, but on other stuff on the server side.

Comment: It not only the V3 validator that does not get called. On check, all get called, on uncheck none get called.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried grouping the controls together? Putting a ValidationGroup on them.

Comment: Yes, I have tried, but it did not work. Also this is a problem, because also other controls than the checkbox (namely the "proceed" button) need to cause validation on the textbox (and all other input controls).